# In .Net, how do I convert between SystemTime and FileTime?

Tags: .net, datetime-conversion, systemtime, filetime

As per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724290(v=vs.85).aspx, a file time is a 64-bit value that represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00 A.M. January 1, 1601 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

To convert between `SystemTime` and `FileTime`, the Windows API functions `SystemTimeToFileTime` and `FileTimeToSystemTime` can be used.

I'm probably missing something here, because I don't think that this is a too rare task. However, searching SO for `[.net] systemtimetofiletime` provides as results just one (downvoted) answer and no relevant questions.

Perhaps it's just a lack of knowledge about the proper terminology, and `SystemTimeToFileTime` is called something very different in the .Net world.

Anyway, the question is, how do I properly convert between `SystemTime` and `FileTime` in .Net?

Comment: Hard to find anything because it is very unusual requirement.  DateTime.Now already returns system-time, DateTime.UtcNow already returns file-time, DateTime.ToUniversalTime() makes the conversion, DateTime.ToFileTime() spits out the OS number.  Hard to guess why you need to ask the question, show us something.

Comment: @HansPassant, is it correct correct to extrapolate that, `DateTime` already "wraps" a SystemTime?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 2):

[Declare the PInvoke function](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/coredll.SystemTimeToFileTime) and call it.

```
//Taken from http://www.codeproject.com/csharp/timezoneconversions.asp?print=true
private static DateTime SystemTimeToDateTime(ref SYSTEMTIME st)
{
        FILETIME ft = new FILETIME();
        SystemTimeToFileTime(ref st, out ft);
        DateTime dt = new DateTime((((long)ft.dwHighDateTime) << 32) | (uint)ft.dwLowDateTime);
        return dt;
}
```

Personally, I search the .NET Framework with a decompiler such as Reflector in such cases for existing usages. Often, Microsoft has already internally called the API that I need. Likely, their PInvoke code will be correct and ready to copy.

Comment: You don't have to use Reflector.  The .NET reference source is available online and has a nice search feature:  https://referencesource.microsoft.com/

Comment: That's good to note @AaronM.Eshbach. The Reflector approach has the advantage that you can just pull 1000 assemblies from C:\ into Reflector and see if any application has the function you need.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're making it way too hard.  In PowerShell, via .NET, you'd do it this way:

```
PS C:\Users\luser> ([System.DateTime]"Jan 05,2018").ToFileTime()
131596092000000000

PS C:\Users\luser> ([System.DateTime]::FromFileTime('131596092000000000'))

Friday, January 5, 2018 12:00:00 AM
```

System.Datetime has a CTOR that accepts just about any type of format you want to provide a datetime and then use the ToFileTime() method to get the int64 value.

Similarly, the Datetime class has a method for converting int64 values to DateTime using the FromFileTime() method.

or am I misunderstanding the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to convert FILETIME from upper and lower 32bit values found in the registry for when a user profile was last used in Windows 10 using PowerShell. Any ideas?

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\SID\

LocalProfileUnloadTimeHigh = 30901163

LocalProfileUnloadTimeLow = 4255800258

```
[System.DateTime]::FromFileTime('425580025830901163')
    
Monday, August 11, 2949 7:23:03 AM

[System.DateTime]::FromFileTime('309011634255800258')
 
Tuesday, March 21, 2580 4:30:25 AM
```